# Tab bar button visible in Xcode, invisible in simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

I've looked all over the place for some sort of solution to this, but no one has described a similar problem.

I have a `UITabBarController` set up in my storyboard with 3 view controllers (and buttons) set up to link to other storyboard references. It all looks fine in the simulator, however, only 2 of the buttons actually show up in the simulator, but I can click on all 3 of them and they function correctly.

[image]

[image]

Things I've done to try and fix the problem:

- Re-ordered the view controllers
- Remade the entire storyboard
- Used different images for the buttons

Nothing has fixed the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sooner did I post the question did I find out the problem. Because the view controllers are storyboard references, I needed to put a `TabBarItem` in the initial view controller of the storyboard being referenced.